# Why does my Monte Carlo simulation not give a normal distribution?

Tags: python, numpy, probability, normal-distribution, probability-distribution

Why does my python Monte Carlo simulation not produce a normal distribution?

```py
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import numpy

P = 0.1
TR = 1_000

l = []

for _ in range(TR):
    tosses = 0
    success = False
    while success == False:
        success = bool(numpy.random.binomial(1, P, 1)[0])
        tosses += 1
    l.append(tosses)

pyplot.hist(l, bins=100)
pyplot.show()
```

[image: Matplotlib graph]

Comment: Because number-of-trials-to-first-success is not distributed normally.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution (with r=1, in your case)

Comment: Also note that using `hist` like that introduces visual artifacts, namely those empty bars, it would look better using `np.unique` and `plt.bar`

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Comment: @lastchance i see.. i wasnt aware. is there some resource that explains why?

Comment: @LeaG, if p is the success on any particular trial, then the case of first success on 1, 2, 3, 4, etc trials correspond to events T, FT, FFT, FFFT, ... and have probabilities p, qp, q^2p, q^3p, ... where q=1-p. This is called a geometric distribution - see the Wikipedia link. Number-of-trials-to-first-success may or may not have been what you intended, but it's what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

Bernoulli trials are not normally distributed in general. I suggest you take a look at theese two links:
https://byjus.com/maths/bernoulli-trials-binomial-distribution/
https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter3/3_1_5_special_discrete_distr.php

I assume your task is related to obtaining  a normal distribution via summing the outcomes of multiple bernolli trials
I think this should work for you:

```
P = 0.1
TR = 1000

l = []

for _ in range(TR):
    tosses = np.random.normal(loc=1/P, scale=1/P, size=1)[0]
    l.append(tosses)

plt.hist(l, bins=100)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: whats the meaning of the x axis and why does it go into the negative?

Comment: @LeaG , they are !simulated! number of trials need for success in bernoulli trial, the negative values occur due to the normal distribution being unbounded in theory. So we could only take a look at the feasible values for the number of trials which would be the portion of the plot starting from x=0 and right side of it but it wouldnt be normally distributed. So they exist to provide the theoretical normal distribution.

Comment: How could you have `0.34` tosses? `-10` tosses? this is clearly incorrect

Comment: @Onyambu You are right that thoose are not feasible values for tosses but those values are like I said simulated theoretical tosses.

Comment: What is a theoretical toss of `0.34`? This is like saying theoretically 3 is less than 2. No you can not have that! tosses do not follow normal distribution. SO you can not claim *theoretical results*. THeoretical results DEPICT real life results. -20 does not in any way DEPICT rl results

Comment: @Onyambu https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Probability_Theory/Book%3A_Introductory_Probability_(Grinstead_and_Snell)/09%3A_Central_Limit_Theorem/9.01%3A_Central_Limit_Theorem_for_Bernoulli_Trials                                              https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/IllustratingTheCentralLimitTheoremWithSumsOfBernoulliRandomV/

Comment: @Onyambu you can also google "Illustrating the Central Limit Theorem with Sums of Bernoulli Random Variables" for further reading.

Comment: The links you sent has nothing to do with tosses but rather a new variable Z which is scaled and centered. and of course it will converge in distribution to normal distribution. ie with CLT, the starting distribution does not matter. As long as you have a large enough sample size, the sample mean will converge in distribution to normal distribution. Note that the question specifically talks about tosses.

Comment: @Onyambu As I have explained in my answer that part I did it for "I assume your task is related to obtaining a normal distribution via summing the outcomes of multiple bernolli trials"

Comment: Note that this is not my task. I am just letting you know that what you did is not correct with regards to question. Also note that sum of bernoulli is not normal but rather binomial. The link you sent even lets you know that the sum of Z is the one that is normal where Z is a normalized variable

Comment: @Onyambu Ok lets agree to disagree :)